# "An In-App Purchase has been returned error" - What is this error?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

What is this error?

Nothing is highlighted - even if I tap on each of the consumable, there is no error inside that.

[image]

Comment: I supposed is a bug in a website, because I have this message in all my apps with In-App and all of them are in Ready for Sale. I don't have any problem just the message in page, do you?

Comment: Yes it is a bug. Even in my apps that doesnt use in app purchases this msg exists.

Comment: I don't see a problem with in-app purchase. Just bought one to confirm. But it may be a bug - or may be something else that we don't know about.